# How to reverse a LinkedList given a specific class: code not giving desired output

Tags: java, linked-list

I would like to write a method `public void reverse()` which reverses a LinkedList using **only** the class below.
So given the list `4 3 2 1` the result should be `1 2 3 4`.

```
public class LinkedList {

    public Node head = null;

    public class Node {
        public int value;
        public Node next;

        Node(int value, Node next) {
            this.value = value
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
}
```

I have managed to write this code and it *kind* of works.

```
public void reverse() {
    Node tmp = head;
    Node prev = null;
    Node nextNode = null;

    while(tmp != null && tmp.next != null) {
        nextNode = tmp.next;
        tmp.next = prev;
        prev = tmp;
        tmp = nextNode;
    }
    head = prev;
}
```

The problem: for a list `4 3 2 1` I get `2 3 4`.
Why is that?

Comment: I have written a method but I seem to be having one value from the list missing when it is reversed.

Comment: I've now tried removing `tmp.next != null` and it works. Is that what you meant? Or did you mean that I should write a condition in addition to those two?

Comment: I just wanted to point you in the right direction. I didnt think it fully through. Simply ask yourself what "special" example data you should carefully test. You reversed a list with 4 members. What about hmm, 0, or 1? Try that, too, and if your code doesnt throw any exceptions, then it is probably good enough ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat thank you for the nudge in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a working solution now which doesn't throw any exceptions.

I simply needed to remove the condition `tmp.next != null`.

```
public void reverse() {
    Node tmp = head;
    Node prev = null;
    Node nextNode = null;

    while(tmp != null) {
        nextNode = tmp.next;
        tmp.next = prev;
        prev = tmp;
        tmp = nextNode;
    }
    head = prev;
}
```